# Building and running odk collect faild on android visuel studio 3.5.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, odk

Using Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm very new in Android visual studio,
I'd like do this :

- Fork and clone Odk Collect application from github
- Edit it from Android visual studio, in order to change some thing like logo, GUI color, icons...

But the issue is that, when I click on Run icon, I get the following error. Notice that I don't have issue with the internet connection at that time when I'm trying to run the App on the Emulator

```
> com.google.android.instantapps.sdk.lib.AdbCommandException: Error
> launching activity
> org.odk.collect.android/com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.DisplayLeakActivity
> Command output: Starting: Intent { flg=0x800
> cmp=org.odk.collect.android/com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.DisplayLeakActivity
> } Error type 3 Error: Activity class
> {org.odk.collect.android/com.squareup.leakcanary.internal.DisplayLeakActivity}
> does not exist.
> 
> Error while Uploading and launching Instant App
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like you're trying to run this is an Instant App. Make sure you're run configuration in Android Studio has Module "collect_app" and Deploy is set to "Default APK". I'd try reimporting if you're unable to set those.

Originally answered on [Github](https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/issues/3456).